# Not getting expected results parsing JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have a web service that look like this

```
[
{
"id_test" : "1",
"title":"test1"
},
{
"id_test" : "2",
"title":"test2"
},{
"id_test" : "3",
"title":"test3"
},
]
```

I use this code to read the json in my program:

```
func downloadJsonWithUrl()
{
    let url = URL(string:"weserviceurl")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                   print(myJson)
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

My question is, at the moment to use use this code below my serialization:

```
if let info = myJson as? NSArray
{
    if let categories = info["title"]
    {
        print(categories)
    }
}
```

does not work. It returns empty. Why?

Comment: Where is that 2nd piece of code relative to the 1st? And why are you using `NSArray` in Swift 3?

Comment: If `info` is an array, then `info["title"]` makes no sense. The index in the array is a numeric value, e.g. `info[0]` is the first dictionary. Or if you want to iterate through all of them you'd `for dictionary in info {...}`, etc.

Comment: To be honest I am new using swift and Im following tutorials from youtube so :(, that's why I am asking, if NSArray is old then what do I need to use ? sorry for so many questions

Comment: You'd use Swift array, e.g. rather than `... as? NSArray` you'd do `... as? [Any]` or `... as? [[String: Any]]`.

Comment: I did this --> if let info = myJson[0] as?  [String:Any]
                        {
                            print(info["ID_Category"])
                        }'
and it returns Optional(1)

Comment: Unrelated, don't use `.mutableContainers` if you don't need to. You should remove the `options` altogether.

Comment: I deleted options now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
func downloadJsonWithUrl() {
  let url = URL(string:"link")

  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [AnyObject]
                    var categories: [String] = []

                    for item in myJson {
                        categories.append(item["title"] as! String)
                    }
                    print(categories)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: @xx_name try now

Comment: @xx_name one more time :D

Comment: it works!!! yeiii!! you are a pro man, now the final question, how do I iterate  to get all the results from "title"?

Comment: Maybe something like that. Did you mean it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use swift `Array` and `Dictionary` types. For example, `... as? [[String: Any]]` says that you're expecting an array of dictionaries:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print("\(error)")
        return
    }

    guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data), let array = json as? [[String: Any]] else {
        print("not JSON array of dictionaries")
        return
    }

    for dictionary in array {
        if let idTest = dictionary["id_test"], let title = dictionary["title"] {
            print("\(idTest): \(title)")
        }
    }
}
```